# How to define a new environment of two text blocks with number?

Tags: environments, mdframed

[image: The new environment]

Hi, I want to define a new environment like the figure above. It has two text blocks with different background color. Block 1 has a short numbered title, such as 'Note' or 'Definition'. Block 2 has a specific indent.

I tried several ways. The first is package `mdframed`. I need two blocks, but the package usually provides one block. All the examples in the manual also have only one block.

The second way is to use `tabular` environment. But I don't know how to make this a new environment with numbers.

Would anybody please give me an example? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this? The `tcolorbox` package can do this using the `tcblower` code. In order to make full use of the package, an environment with `\DeclareTColorbox` should be used, for some options and to use an automated `\tcblower`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{mynote}[1][]{
  enhanced,
  sharp corners,
  bicolor,
  colback={white!60!yellow},
  colbacklower={white!20!yellow},
  coltitle={black},
  title={Note},
  detach title,before upper={\tcbtitle~\thetcbcounter~\par},
  before lower={\parindent20pt},
  #1
}



\begin{document}

\begin{mynote}
  Foo
  \tcblower
  Bar
\end{mynote}

\begin{mynote}[colbacklower={white},before lower={\parindent40pt}]
  Foo
  \tcblower
  Bar
\end{mynote}



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Christian. Your answer solved my question. tcolorbox is really a useful package. After reading part of the manual of this package, I learned a lot. With the use of detach title, I can get what exact I want (put the title in the upper box with thetcbcunter).

Comment: @ChangjieGUAN: I would say, `tcolorbox` is one of the most powerful packages concerning colored boxes etc. I wished I had invented it ;-) If you don't mind you can accept my answer ;-)